# Block scripts from allowed URLs

Tags: http2, content-security-policy

### 1. Summary

I don't find, how I can block scripts from URLs, that I allow in Content-Security-Policy.

---

### 2. Limitations

I have a static site. It would be nice if any solutions for JavaScript include JQuery and/or any other libraries; But not solutions for dynamic sites.

---

### 3. Target

I include to my site third-party frames, videos, widgets and so on, that can include analytics scripts. I don't want visitors of my site to be tracked. I want to block requests.

Visitors of my site can install [**some browser extension**](https://myshadow.org/prevent-online-tracking), that prevents online tracking. But users without browser extensions will be tracked.

I can't find how I can prevent online tracking on my site, if site visitors don't have any blocking tools.

More details [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50386243/5951529).

---

### 4. Example

I add Streamable video to HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://streamable.com">
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:100%;height:0px;position:relative;padding-bottom:100.000%;"><iframe src="https://streamable.com/s/aqg9y/uknjqm" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;overflow:hidden;"></iframe></div>
</body>

</html>
```

- Repl.it:

  - [**Source**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/SashaContent-Security-Policydefault-src-Streamable)
  - [**Demo page**](https://sashacontent-security-policydefault-src-streamable--kristinita.repl.co/)

---

### 5. Steps to reproduce

I disable all ads and track blockers in Firefox for demo page → I open Firefox native console.

---

### 6. Expected behavior

- **Block**: **https://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js** **and** **https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js** — analytics scripts
- **Allow**: any another Streamable scripts

---

### 7. Actual behavior

- **Allow**: all Streamable scripts include **https://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js** **and** **https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js**

  [image: Allow]

---

### 8. Not helped

1. Google, Stack Overflow searching
2. I try read documentation:

   - [**Content-Security-Policy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy)
   - [**default-src**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/default-src)
3. [**Do Not Track**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/DNT) directive:

   - [**Source**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/SashaStreamable-DNT)
   - [**Demo page**](https://sashastreamable-dnt--kristinita.repl.co/)

Answer (score 1):

An iframe loads a completely independent document, and if allowed to load, then it is not subject to that top level page's CSP.

So you have your top level page which implements a CSP. It then loads another page in the iframe. That page is allowed to be loaded as an iframe for the top level page because the top-level CSP allows that domain to load.

The iframed page is then loaded completely separately. It does not have a CSP on it, so it's free to load anything - including the analytics that is reference on that page.

You can get some of what you want with the [sandbox attribute of the iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) - however it is a bit more limited: It is not possible to allow some scripts and not others, for example. And tracking can be done with images.

Another option would be to proxy the 3rd party content via your server, and you inject the CSP into that iframed page, and then have your top level page load that altered page. For example:

```
 <iframe src="https://example.com?pagetoload=streamable.com/s/aqg9y/uknjqm" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This would also be easier with the CSP applied via a HTTP header rather than a meta tag so you don't even need to alter the HTML returned by the streamable page.

Note that having a completely open proxy, where any page can be loaded can lead to lots of other other security issues including, but not limited to:

- This page now exists on that domain, as far as that browser is concerned, so has access to that domain's cookies.
- I can display https://example.com?pagetoload=evil.example.com and avoid any browser security that might otherwise block evil.example.com.

and lots of other similar problems...